# SQL Server Management Studio 2005 - Change Default Directory for Backup Location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, configuration, ssms

Using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005 - To Restore a Database:

- Restore Database
- `(*) From Device:`
- Click "`...`"  Button
- `Backup media:  File`
- Click "`Add`" Button
- Popup Window: "`Locate Backup File`"

That window Defaults to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Backup`

How do I configure MS SQL Server Management Studio to look in `D:\data\databases\`
instead of looking in  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Backup` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the registry, edit the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\BackupDirectory` value to point to `d:\data\databases`

Comment: I had been curious if their was a way to configure it from within the gui, but these registry changes will do just as well.

Comment: I assume this requires a restart of the service?

Comment: @KyleLanser no, it's Microsoft, it just doesn't work this way :)

Answer (score 5):

It's stored in the registry.

On my computer, it's at...

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer

There is a registry key named BackupDirectory

I suspect the registry key will be in a different location for you (I have 64 bit vista).  I did a search in my registry for 'MSSQL.1\Backup' to find it.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, here's a reg file entry to do this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer]
"BackupDirectory"="D:\\data\\databases\\"
```